# What message storage is the best to use for ActiveMQ?

Tags: storage, activemq-classic

**ActiveMq v 5.5** comes with default message storage configured as **KahaDB**. Does anyone use it in enterprise level solutions? Should it be replaced with **MSSQL** instead? And what benefits can each of them have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The persistence mechanism should be based on your application's needs.  A closely related concern is going to be failover/availability.

Speaking purely of the speed of message persistence, KahaDB is going to be the fastest; it's tuned specifically for patterns surrounding messaging (writing/reading/discarding).  Were you to use something like MSSQL, even with journaling enabled, you're going to give up orders of magnitude (in mgs/sec) in efficiency.  This setup works well if you are concerned with publishing high volumes of messages and are willing to leave message recovery up to an admin or some "invented-here" process.

So, why would you choose a different persistence mechanism?  High availability.

Re: something like a relational database, it's probably something already available in your enterprise, meaning someone's (hopefully) gone through the effort of clustering and testing disaster recovery.  This means you should be able to have a master/slave setup and your messages will be recoverable if a master were to go down.  The slave will detect a loss of lock and start using the exact same message store.  This setup is ideal if your performance threshold is much lower but you are extremely concerned about up-time and ensuring that you can always publish/subscribe messages.

Regardless, in a well-tuned system, we are talking >= hundreds msgs/sec so performance considerations are likely *not* going to be your first concern.  Should performance *really* be that crucial, I'd consider looking at something like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com), which definitely lends itself well to being extremely efficient at the cost of making high availability more complex to set up.

Here's a [discussion on some of the failover options with ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-message-store.html).  I've settled on using a shared file master/slave setup with a KahaDB being shared on a SAN.  Seems to be a nice middle-ground solution.

Comment: Thank you Joshua, very good answer! We are actually planning to use MS SQL for persistence, which is setup on cluster. Our main concern is not a performance at the time but reliability and guarantee that every single message sent to queues is never lost and is always available for interested consumers.

Comment: What are the volumes of messages your setup of KahaDB on a SAN handles/stores? What is an average lifetime of messages in your system?

Comment: I've benchmarked ~ 1k/sec using Kaha on a SAN, but I'm currently working on a new project that hasn't made it into production yet.  In a test environment, it's performing spectacularly :-)  In a previous gig, we had some messages with a life-span of a few hours being journaled into MySQL and we were benchmarking ~250/sec.  In this current implementation, we are intentionally keeping the messages small and will ramp up workers so that messages don't live for much more than a few seconds.

Comment: BTW, those benchmark numbers are highly irrelevant.  I've seen things like message size/number consumers/memory tweaks push that number closer to 3k/sec.  Best thing to do is benchmark using some real-world data and then see if your performance degradation is an issue.  Like you said, my main concern was reliability; the performance was way above what I needed, even at the lowest point.

Comment: Joshua, when you say that KahaDB is order of magnitude faster, do you have any number proving it? This is something that makes a lot of sense, and I fully agree with you and your expectations; yet, this is quite a strong statement, and should be backed by actual numbers.

Comment: @RobertoLiffredo any empirical data i present is only going to be relevant for my particular case.  the best thing you can do is benchmark stats, given your own particular scenario, and (dis)prove it for yourself.  and, not to be snarky, but my comparison of 250/sec in MySQL vs. 3k/sec in Kaha would be one order of magnitude difference :-)